# Unable to test whether a file exists in Bash

Tags: bash, tilde-expansion

Consider the following Bash script:

```
function dosomething {
    local fname="~/.bash_profile"
    if [[ -f "$fname" ]]; then
        echo "proceeding"
    else
        echo "skipping"
    fi
}

dosomething
```

I always get "skipped" although I know that ~/.bash_profile exists. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`~` is only expanded by the shell if it's unquoted. When it's quoted it's a literal tilde symbol.

```
local fname=~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll be using `'local fname="/Users/$(whoami)/.bash_profile"` instead.

Comment: That seems like way more work than simply unquoting the `~`. Also, it technically makes an assumption about where the user's home directory is that doesn't have to be true. Use `$HOME` if you don't want to use `~`.